# Google Speech API React-Native Error when running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, google-speech-api

Trying to move the Google Speech to text API into React-Native. This is the code that I have so far. The error that I get is this: "bundling failed: Error:

> Unable to resolve module `fs` from `/Users/Desktop/finalTest/final3/App.js`: Module `fs` does not exist in the Haste module map".

I tried running the suggested commands but it still didnt work:

> 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>
>    2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>    3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
>    4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});

const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

const API_KEY = "./keyfile.json";
const fileName = "./audio.raw";

// Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
const file = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
const audioBytes = file.toString("base64");

// The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
const audio = {
  content: audioBytes
};
const config = {
  encoding: "LINEAR16",
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  languageCode: "en-US"
};
const request = {
  audio: audio,
  config: config
};

const apiKey = API_KEY;
const url = `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${apiKey}`;

axios
  .request({
    url,
    method: "POST",
    data: request
  })
  .then(response => {
    const transcription = response.data.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join("\n");
    console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("err :", err);
  });

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `fs`, or any node core modules for that matter, in react native. [You can read more about that here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment), but it's best to think of your JS as being pure JavaScript without any added APIs or modules.

If you need filesystem access then you'll need a third party library, for example [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

Comment: Replaced the reading of the audio file with this:
 
`const audioBytes = rfs.readFile(fileName, "base64")`
Now I get this error: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')

I installed and linked it using: `react-native link react-native-fs`